# How to display arabic keyboard in Ionic IOS App

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

We are using **ionic-plugin-keyboard** in our Ionic IOS Application.

When a user changes the language to Arabic, we want to enable Arabic keyboard for all the text fields.

Not finding any support in the plugin page.

Comment: have you got any solution. Right now I am installing arabic keyboard app from app store and playstore.